# Need Help Overriding Mage Model

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, overrides, model

I need to override

> Mage->Adminhtml->Model->System->Config->Source->Notification->Frequency.php

I followed the instructions outlined in [Inchoo override magento model](http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/)

I tested the changes i need by editing the original mage file... which worked. I then copied that edited file to my module

> Myname->Modulename->Model->System->Config->Source->Notification->Frequency.php

Then placed the original file back in the mage folder.

I then edited the class of **frequency.php**:

```
class Myname_Modulename_Model_System_Config_Source_Notification_Frequency
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            0   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('0 Minute'),
            1   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('1 Hour'),
            2   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('2 Hours'),
            6   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('6 Hours'),
            12  => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('12 Hours'),
            24  => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('24 Hours')
        );
    }
}
```

I then added this to the **config.xml** file:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <rewrite>
                <item>Openstream_Notifications_Model_System_Config_Source_Notification_Frequency</item>
                </rewrite>
            </modulename>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

But i am unable to see the override changes in the systems area, please help by telling me what i'm doing wrong. its my first time overriding a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have `<modulename>` tag while overriding and also you will need to tell magento what file path is it exactly? In our case `adminhtml_system_config_source_notification_frequency`

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                <system_config_source_notification_frequency>Openstream_Notifications_Model_System_Config_Source_Notification_Frequency</system_config_source_notification_frequency>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

This should work however for neat coding I would also put my files under `adminhtml` folder since it belongs there. It will help you in future to know which file/folder belongs to admin/front section.

So your folder structure would be: `Openstream_Notifications_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Notification_Frequency`.
If you follow this then will need to change this exactly as follow:

```
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                    <system_config_source_notification_frequency>Openstream_Notifications_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Notification_Frequency</system_config_source_notification_frequency>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it helped you.